# Reverse Engineering Thought Process

Tags: process

About an year back I had seen a PDF of some research work that had been shared at /r/reverseengineering that tried to reason and understand the thought process involved in Reverse Engineering.

Unfortunately I did not save the link and I'm having trouble finding it on reddit. I was wondering if anyone had a link of the same handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably refering to this document: http://www.dtic.mil/cgi-bin/GetTRDoc?AD=ADA557042

Comment: I'm sorry, I get a "Error - Request Denied, please try again.".

Comment: Yes it's weird you need to click several times otherwise http://maijin.fr/ADA557042.pdf